# Pesquisar por todos ou apenas um campo do formulário

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Estou tendo problemas com um formulário em meu blog de WordPress, tenho o seguinte formulário que está no arquivo *functions.php*.

```
function terapeuta_search_scripts(){
wp_enqueue_script('terapeutas', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/terapeutas.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
wp_localize_script('terapeutas', 'ajax_url', admin_url('admin-ajax.php'));
}

function terapeuta_search(){
terapeuta_search_scripts();

ob_start();
?>
<div id="bed-search">
    <form action="" method="get">
        <input placeholder="Pesquise um nome..." id="terapeuta-nome" type="text" name="terapeuta-nome" />
        <select id="terapeuta-estado" name="terapeuta-estado">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Estados</option>
            <option value="AL">AL</option>
            <option value="BA">BA</option>
            <option value="CE">CE</option>
            <option value="DF">DF</option>
            <option value="GO">GO</option>
            <option value="MG">MG</option>
            <option value="MS">MS</option>
            <option value="MT">MT</option>
            <option value="RJ">RJ</option>
            <option value="RN">RN</option>
            <option value="RS">RS</option>
            <option value="SP">SP</option>
            <option value="SC">SC</option>
            <option value="PR">PR</option>
        </select>
        <select id="terapeuta-cidade" name="terapeuta-cidade">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Cidades</option>
            <option value="Armação dos Búzios">Armação dos Búzios</option>
            <option value="Atibaia">Atibaia</option>
            <option value="Belo Horizonte">Belo Horizonte</option>
            <option value="Brasília">Brasília</option>
            <option value="Bueno Brandão">Bueno Brandão</option>
            <option value="Campinas">Campinas</option>
            <option value="Campos do Jordão">Campos do Jordão</option>
            <option value="Cianorte">Cianorte</option>
            <option value="Curitiba">Curitiba</option>
            <option value="Chapecó">Chapecó</option>
            <option value="Delfim Moreira">Delfim Moreira</option>
            <option value="Florianópolis">Florianópolis</option>
            <option value="Foz do Iguaçu">Foz do Iguaçu</option>
            <option value="Garça">Garça</option>
            <option value="Guarantã do Norte">Guarantã do Norte</option>
            <option value="Ilhabela">Ilhabela</option>
            <option value="Maceió">Maceió</option>
            <option value="Maracaju">Maracaju</option>
            <option value="Miguel Pereira">Miguel Pereira</option>
            <option value="Morungaba">Morungaba</option>
            <option value="Natal">Natal</option>
            <option value="Piratininga">Piratininga</option>
            <option value="Porto Alegre">Porto Alegre</option>
            <option value="Rio de Janeiro">Rio de Janeiro</option>
            <option value="Santana de Parnaíba">Santana de Parnaíba</option>
            <option value="São Paulo">São Paulo</option>
            <option value="Santo André">Santo André</option>
            <option value="Sinop">Sinop</option>
            <option value="Sorocaba">Sorocaba</option>
            <option value="Ubatuba">Ubatuba</option>
            <option value="Uruçuca">Uruçuca</option>
            <option value="Uberlândia">Uberlândia</option>
            <option value="Volta Redonda">Volta Redonda</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Buscar Terapeuta</button>
    </form>

    <ul style="list-style-type:none;"></ul>

</div>
<?php
return ob_get_clean();
}
```

E no meu arquivo JavaScript está o seguinte código...

```
$ = jQuery;

var bedSearch = $("#bed-search");
var searchForm = bedSearch.find("form");

searchForm.submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

    var data = {
        action : "terapeuta_search",
        nome : bedSearch.find("#terapeuta-nome").val(),
        estado : bedSearch.find("#terapeuta-estado").val(),
        cidade : bedSearch.find("#terapeuta-cidade").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url : ajax_url,
        data : data,
        success : function(response){
            bedSearch.find("ul").empty();
            for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
                console.log(response[i]);
                var html = "<li id='terapeuta-" + response[i].id + "'><a style='color:orange;' href='" + response[i].permalink + "'>" + response[i].nome + "</a></li>";
                bedSearch.find("ul").append(html);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

No momento a pesquisa funciona se eu preencher [nome + estado + cidade] ou [estado + cidade], mas estou perdido em como fazer para que possa ser possivel pesquisar apenas por um dos campos estando preenchido.

Comment: Se possível poste o código de sua `action terapeuta_search`

Comment: O problema não está no JavaScript, está na consulta ao banco que deve exigir os os dados para retornar algum valor. Teríamos que ver como está sendo feita essa consulta para sugerir uma alteração.